# How to integrate LDAP with KIE Workbench?

Tags: ldap, drools, kie, kie-workbench, wildfly-14

I have setup KIE Workbench on Wildfly Server. I need to integrate existing LDAP authentication into KIE Workbench. How to do so?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I do have ldap url, but couldn't find a way to integrate it with workbench. Any good reference will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

- Create security-domain like as in standalone.xml file

  ```
  <security-domain name="brms" cache-type="default">
  <authentication>
      <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag="required">
          <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://10.10.10.10:389"/>
          <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
          <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
          <module-option name="bindDN" value="cn=orgname,cn=Users,dc=SPNEGO,dc=com"/>
          <module-option name="bindCredential" value="test"/>
          <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="dc=SPNEGO,dc=com"/>
          <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(sAMAccountName={0})"/>
          <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="cn=Users,dc=SPNEGO,dc=com"/>
          <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(member={1})"/>
          <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="memberOf"/>
          <module-option name="roleNameAttributeID" value="cn"/>
          <module-option name="roleRecursion" value="0"/>
          <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN" value="true"/>
          <module-option name="java.naming.referral" value="follow"/>
          <module-option name="searchScope" value="SUBTREE_SCOPE"/>
      </login-module>
  </authentication>
  ```
- Define same security domain name in jboss-web.xml file in security-domain tag.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://bbalasub.wordpress.com/2018/09/24/jbpm-authentication-and-authorization-using-ldap/), changes required in 3 places :

1. standalone.xml
2. jbpm.user.info.properties
3. jbpm.usergroup.callback.properties

process is described in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UpT92-GIxc) video, source code can be found [here](https://github.com/bbalakriz/ldap-jbpm-auth/tree/master)